# Virtualbox - Can't start Windows Server 2008 r2. Loops "Window's Is Loading Files..."

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, virtualbox

I have a vdi file that is using Windows Server 2008 R2.

Each time I try to start it, I get this message:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/azKpG.png

It would then display a "Windows is loading files..." page and repeatedly loops the message:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTONv.png

My Laptop Specs:
Processor - Intel Core 2 Duo T6500 2.10GHz
RAM - 4 GB RAM
OS - Windows 7 Pro 64 bit

Virtualbox Guest OS:
Base Memory - 512 MB
Video Memory - 32 MB

Not sure what to do. I pretty much searched through all of Google and can't seem to find an answer or any tutorials related to this issue.

Any information or advice would greatly be appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved.  The Intel Core 2 Duo T6500 mobile processor does not support 64-bit Guest OS.

Below is link for anyone interested

http://ark.intel.com/VTList.aspx

Answer (score 4):

usually this error is occured when you try to configure your VDI image for any incompatible OS architecture selection.

for eg: VDI file is of Windows 7 32bit, but you are tyring to configure this using a Windows 764bit option.

The best solution to overcome this is to use the "Export Appliance" option from file menu and then, "Import Appliance". Benifit is, the wizard automatically identifies which OS architecture it was originally configured for.

Comment: I have the same symptoms as the OP but with a Linux host and a Centrino CPU.

Centrino is not listed in Srijith's answer, so I wonder what's the issue in my case?

Comment: what are the specs of your Centrino processor?

Comment: I had exported OVF from VMWare and then imported it to VirtualBox, but got this loop. Changing the "Version" of the machine to "Windows 2008 (64-bit)" from "Windows 2008" fixed it